# Defining a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ from a particular $F:R\to R$.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm confused about the proof below from Donald Cohn's *Measure Theory*:

In particular I don't see how compactness of $[t,x]$ is used in the end of the argument.

The following seems to work, but does not require any of the $\delta_{n}$'s.

Once $t<x$ is chosen in the second paragraph so that $F(t) < \epsilon$, what is wrong with the following simpler argument?

$\begin{eqnarray*}F(x) - \epsilon &<& F(x) - F(t)\\
                                  &=& \mu^{*}((t,x])\text{, (from the check  that }\mu^{*}\text{ is an outer measure)}\\
                                  &\leq& \mu^{*}(-\infty,x]\text{, (by monotonicity)}
\end{eqnarray*}$

yielding 
$$F(x) \leq \mu^{*}(-\infty,x] + \epsilon$$.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this oversight.  The problem is that $\mu^{*}[t,x]$ need not be $F(x) - F(t)$, since $F$ is only continuous from the right.